# assembla and github

Tags: git, project-management, github, assembla

I am using assembla and github and I have set up the correct Post-Receive URLs (Service hooks) to link the two services together and use powerful commit messages. I have the following issue.

I have have 3 spaces with Post-Receive URLs (Service hooks) set up on github, all 3 spaces successfully receive the commit messages. But only 1 space successfully associates the commit messages with the appropriate ticket.

e.g. I have set up a ticket in each space called "Test Commits" Using the commit message "Test Commit Re #1" Each space will pick up the commit and I can see it in the Stream. But only 1 space associates the commit with the ticket.

The only thing I can tell is different is the 2 that don't work have commits against a branch and the 1 that does work has a commit against the master.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I like Assembla (its free its simple and it works). I joined irc.freenode.org and found also a room #assembla (very nice in support).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange, since the branch shouldn't be a factor.

If it is reproducible, that can be a good start for a [trac Assembla ticket](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/AssemblaSupport/support/tickets).
(which the OP [Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123140/lizard) did: **[issue 654](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/AssemblaSupport/support/tickets/654-github-assemble-ticket-commits)**)

---

It appears to be an [issue on Assembla side](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/AssemblaSupport/support/tickets/654-github-assemble-ticket-commits?comment=11122601#comment%3A11122601):

> *At the moment* **we are not processing commit message if commit were located in non-main branch (in git, master)**.
>   As you've mentioned this topic, we decided to review our decision, and process all comments.

... and this ticket is now solved. The [git-tool page (accessed through login only)](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/idio-site/github_tool) mentions:

> #### How to update Assembla tickets from git commits
>
> - Use **`Closes #4`** to close ticket 4.
>     closed, close, fix, fixed, and fixes will also close a ticket.
> - **`Test #4`** will mark the ticket as "Ready to Test".
> - **`Re #4`**, `references`, `refs` and `see` will add a comment to the target ticket but leave it untouched.

And this now works on every branches, not just master.

Comment: Thanks I have submitted the ticket. To confirm it was an issue with the branch, I switched to the master branch on a repo space that wasn't working did a commit and it all worked fine.

Comment: @Lizard: all right! Do you have the url of your ticket?

Comment: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/AssemblaSupport/support/tickets/654-github-assemble-ticket-commits#last_comment

Comment: @Lizard: thank you for the link. I have included it in the answer, and will monitor its resolution.

Comment: @Lizard, in case you are interested assembla has github integration now. If you go to the admin tab of your space and then click on Tools you'll see the github connector there.